# DB2 - Generate random string with specific length

Tags: sql, db2

I need to update the data in few fields of a DB2 LUW database with random strings. This is for masking sensitive information. I have used the following function in Oracle and looking for equivalent in DB2:

```
DBMS_RANDOM.STRING ('L', length(NAME))
```

Here NAME is the field and L stands for lower case. This function generates a lower case string with the same length as the field value.

I have found the following way to generate a random string in DB2:

```
CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+65)
|| CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+65)
|| CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+65)
|| CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+65)
|| CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+65)
|| CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+65)
|| CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+65)
|| CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+65)
```

My Queries - 
1) How can I generate random strings in lower case ?
2) How can I restrict the length of the generated string to be same as the length of the field values (similar to the oracle function) ?

Thanks

Comment: The above concatenates 8 characters. Each character is generated from the range of upper case letters. Adapt it.

Comment: @data_henrik, could you please suggest how can I restrict the length based on the length of the value in the field (similar to the oracle function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rajat use this with Rpad for length in place of 1000000000

```
TRANSLATE ( CHAR(BIGINT(RAND() * 10000000000 )), 'abcdefghij', '1234567890' )
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. I have used it with the SUBSTRING function - SUBSTRING(TRANSLATE ( CHAR(BIGINT(RAND() * 1000000000000 )), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', '1234567890' ),1,length(FIRSTNAME),CODEUNITS16)

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- Use `97` (ASCII "a") instead of `65` (ASCII "A").
- Create a long string and get a substring of it according to the length you want.

For example, if you assume your names are 30 chars length at most:

```
select name, 
  left(
     CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97) || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97) || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97)
  || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97) || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97) || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97)
  || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97) || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97) || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97)
  || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97) || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97) || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97)
  || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97) || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97) || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97)
  || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97) || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97) || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97)
  || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97) || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97) || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97)
  || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97) || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97) || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97)
  || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97) || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97) || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97)
  || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97) || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97) || CHR(INT(RAND()*26)+97)
  , least(30, length(name)) )
from product;
```

Result:

```
NAME      2                               
--------  --------
Gonzalez  qldycihq
Coyote    rocpnw
```

Make sure you use the expression `min(30, length(name))` for the length. Otherwise, DB2 crashes if you want to take more characters than available from a varchar.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This solves one part of my query. Second part is to restrict the length based on the length of field value (similar to the oracle function)

Comment: Here you go. I hope it helps.